# Determining When the JavaScript Dropbox Datastore API is Done Inserting

Tags: javascript, dropbox-api

I'm doing an import of a large number of records (2000-3000) into a Dropbox datastore using the [JavaScript API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/docs/js). I'm trying to block the UI until the import completes because if the user navigates away from the page, the import terminates part of the way through.

Here's my code with comments of what's happening:

```
//This shows a "loading" spinner
showLoader('Standby','Importing logbook...');

//Fire import function
writeToDropbox('aircraft', data.aircraft);

function writeToDropbox(tableName, dataArray){

  //Write up to 100 items per delta
  for(var i = 0; i < dataArray.length && i < 100; i++) {
    //Write to Dropbox
    datastore.getTable(tableName).insert(dataArray[i]);
  }

  if(i < dataArray.length) { 
    //More to write
    window.setTimeout(function(){
      //After a tick, continue from where we left off              
      writeToDropbox(tableName, dataArray.slice(i));      
    }, 1);
  }

  //Check progress
  if(dataArray.length == 0){
    //Writing complete... show the confirmation modal
    hideLoader();
    $('#modal-done').show(); //(!) This happens before all the records are inserted
  }  
}
```

The problem I'm having is that the JavaScript all executes and my app shows the confirmation modal, but in the background the datastore API is still inserting records.

How do I reliably determine when the API is done inserting records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/61/checking-the-datastore-sync-status-in-javascript.

Check `datastore.getSyncStatus().uploading`.

Comment: I just tried this and it's working great. I'm not sure how I missed it in the docs. Thanks a ton for your help!